# ¿Como hacer un crop a una imagen con css?

Tags: css, img

Hola amigos mi consulta es esa necesito mostrar solamente una porcion de una imagen .
Hay alguna forma  de especificar que parte de la imagen se vea?
usando css o no se si la etiqueta img tiene algunos parametros para dicho caso.
Si alguno sabe seria de gran ayuda gracias :).

Comment: Qué es lo que has intentado hasta hora?

Comment: bueno probe con background-position  pero con las pripiedades top center bottom

Comment: Si te ha servido alguna de las respuestas deberías marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que esto te sirva:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 30% 5%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image</h2>
<img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris">

</body>
</html>
```

Para mover puedes cambiar los valores de object position.

La probe con la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias por responder amigo. Lo voy a probar aver que tal de momento pareciera que puede servir.

Answer (score 2):

existe la propiedad `background-position` en CSS, la cual te permite colocar la imagen, segun las coordenadas que le indiques.

```css
.img{
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/contact-info-icon-vector-id889473166?k=6&m=889473166&s=612x612&w=0&h=L8ak00zJlTx4XaJ6dpEVBNuSgrY9hfH0t0pCCeud11Y=");
  background-position: -55px -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">

</div>
```

Como ves, la imagen es una imagen llena de iconos, y en el ejemplo solo se muestra 1.
A mi contenedor `div.img`, le coloque un tamaño con `width` y `height` para conseguir el objetivo

El primer valor mueve de derecha a izquierda y el segundo de arriba a abajo

Esta es la imagen original[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias amigo creo que esto es lo que busco